# QGIS map legend rendering problem

Tags: qgis, legend

The maps look good, and the legend symbols match the maps.  Once converted to .pdf the map legend symbols degrade to basically nothing.  Horizontal red line patterns, or any colored line patterns for that matter are degraded to "pink" or "colored" legend boxes after conversion to PDF, which makes the legend useless.

Comment: please add an example and which version of QGIS you are using

Comment: What DPI is your layout set to? What settings are you using in the PDF Export Options?

Comment: Also, please add a screenshot before & after the export.